# is there any way to count the number of iterations in bubble-sort loop?

Tags: java, iteration, bubble-sort, counting

I'm completly new to Java and programming at all so sorry for all my mistakes. ;)
I'm supposed to write a programme with bubble-sorting method. And then I should count (and print) the number of comparisons.  I'm not sure how to do this... :/

```
public class ArrayUtils {
    void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
        boolean swapped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                    int tmp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = tmp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            if (!swapped) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int tmp : array) {
            System.out.printf("|| %3d ", tmp);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Could you help me? Or at least give some hint? ;)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Initialize a counter to zero. Then, every time you do a comparison, increment the counter by one.

Comment: it works... just it... :D it was so easy... :D thank you!